# Using FFTW and evaluating the resulting Fourier series

Tags: c++, fft, fftw, dft

I'm new to FFTW. I want to decompose a function into a Fourier series. So far, I don't manage to do it. My code is the following:

```
  // 1) Create discretizations for my function 'my_function'
  int N = 100; // number of discretizations
  float x_step = (x_end - x_start) / ((float)(N - 1));
  fftw_complex *Input, *Output;
  fftw_plan my_plan;
  Input = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
  Output = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
  float x = x_start;
  ForIndex(i, N) {
    Input[i][0] = my_function(x);
    cout << "Input[" << i << "]=" << Input[i][0] << endl;
    Input[i][1] = 0;
    x += x_step;
  }

  my_plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, Input, Output, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

  fftw_execute(my_plan);

  // 3) Evaluation - this is the part I am confused with
  // I should get something very close to 'my_function' when I plot, shouldn't I?
  ForIndex(i, N) {
    float sum = 0;
    float x = (float)i;
    sum = Output[0][0] / 2.0f;
    for (int k = 1; k < N; k++) {
      // Fourier series
      // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series
      float s = 2.0f*(float)M_PI * (float)k * x / (float)N;
      sum += Output[k][0] * std::cos(s) + Output[k][1] * std::sin(s);
      // I also tried
      // sum += Output[k][0] * std::sin(s + Output[k][1]);
      // to no avail
    }
    cout << "For x=" << x << ", y=" << (sum / (float)N) << endl;
  }
```

The result I get is bogus: I just get oscillating waves when I plot the series.

Could somebody give me a clue as to how properly evaluate the resulting Fourier series?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to the expected result ! Two points to get the right output :

- The first term `Output` is the average of the input signal. So it is `sum = Output[0][0];`, not `sum = Output[0][0] / 2.0f;`
- `i` is the complex such that `i*i==-1` Hence, as imaginary parts are multiplied, a minus sign must be added to the result. Hence :

  ```
  sum += Output[k][0] * std::cos(s) - Output[k][1] * std::sin(s);
  ```

Here is a corrected piece of code to be compiled by `g++ main.cpp -o main -lfftw3 -lm` :

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

float my_function(float x){
    return x;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    // 1) Create discretizations for my function 'my_function'
    int N = 100; // number of discretizations
    float x_end=1;
    float x_start=0;
    int i;
    float x_step = (x_end - x_start) / ((float)(N - 1));
    fftw_complex *Input, *Output;
    fftw_plan my_plan;
    Input = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    Output = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    float x = x_start;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        Input[i][0] = my_function(x);
        cout << "Input[" << i << "]=" << Input[i][0] << endl;
        Input[i][1] = 0;
        x += x_step;
    }

    my_plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, Input, Output, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(my_plan);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){ 
      printf("%d %g+%gi\n",i,Output[i][0],Output[i][1]);
    }

    // 3) Evaluation - this is the part I am confused with
    // I should get something very close to 'my_function' when I plot, shouldn't I?
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        float sum = 0;
        float x = (float)i;
        sum = Output[0][0];
        for (int k = 1; k < N; k++) {
            // Fourier series
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series
            float s = 2.0f*(float)M_PI * (float)k * x / (float)N;
            sum += Output[k][0] * std::cos(s) - Output[k][1] * std::sin(s);
            // I also tried
            // sum += Output[k][0] * std::sin(s + Output[k][1]);
            // to no avail
        }
        cout << "For i=" << i <<" x="<<x_start+x_step*i<< " f(x)="<<my_function(x_start+x_step*i)<<" y=" << (sum / (float)N) << endl;
    }

}
```

I also added something to print the coefficient of the Fourier transform. Since the input is a real signal, coefficients of frequencies `k` and `N-k` are conjugates. Since `N=100`, look at frequencies 49 and 51 or 48 and 52.

Hence, the library fftw provides [functions dedicated to real inputs](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data), `fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()` for real to complex and `fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d()`. Half of the frequencies( `(N+1)/2` in fact) are stored and computed

To come back to the real world, you may use  a second plan, with [`FFTW_BACKWARD`](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs) :

```
my_plan2 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, Output, input, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```